# Python not outputting results of a sql query

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to write a program that asks for a user input of either a first name and last name or a customer ID in a sql database. The first part if the user inputs a customer ID, I seem to have figured out, and the program runs and outputs desired output. However, if the user inputs the choice to do it by name, the program works up until when it is supposed to output the results of the sql query. At which point the program just ends. I can't seem to figure out why it is not outputting the sql query for the lift of me. Here is my code:

```
while (True): # Begins a while loop to validate the user inputs a correct value.
    ui = input("Would you like to lookup the customer by Customer ID (1) or Name (2)? >")
    try: # Tries to convert the users input into an integer if possible
        ui = int(ui)
    except: # If not possible it informs the user their input was invalid and tries again. 
        print("Invalid selection.")
    
    if (ui == 1): # Breaks the while loop if a valid input is detected.
        break
    elif (ui == 2): # Breaks the while loop if a valid input is detected. 
        break
    
    else:
        print("Please enter either 1 or 2 to make a selection.")

if(ui == 1):
        while(True):
            cid = input("What is the Customer ID? >") 
            try: # Attempts to turn the input into an integer.
                cid = int(cid)
                cursor.execute("SELECT C.CustID, C.Fname, C.Lname, C.Gender, C.CustState, U.Population  FROM Customer C INNER JOIN USState U ON C.CustState = U.StateID  WHERE C.CustID = %d" % (cid))
                for x in cursor: # If a valid integer is entered for customer ID, a SQL Query is outputted with the results matching the CustID.
                    print("Customer ID: %d, First Name: %s, Last Name: %s, Gender: %s, State: %s, State Population: %s." %(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],int(x[5])))
                break # The while loop is broken.
            
            except:
                print("Please enter an integer.")

          
elif(ui == 2):
    cid = input("What is the customer's first name? (press enter for blank) >")
    xid = input("What is the customer's last name?")
    cursor.execute("SELECT C.CustID, C.Fname, C.Lname, C.Gender, C.CustState, U.Population  FROM Customer C INNER JOIN USState U ON C.CustState = U.StateID  WHERE C.Fname = '%s' AND C.Lname = '%s'" % (cid, xid))
    for x in cursor: 
        print("Customer ID: %d, First Name: %s, Last Name: %s, Gender: %s, State: %s, State Population: %s." %(x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],int(x[5])))
```

Comment: Are you sure that your input would get results if you just manually queried the database? If there aren't any errors, but it isn't printing anything out then it seems to me like there are no results being returned.

Comment: Remember that the capitalization must match exactly.  If the name is "Fred", then "fred" won't match.  And you should let the database connector do the substitution, as in `cursor.execute("...WHERE C.Fname=? AND C.Lname=?;", (cid,xid) )`

Comment: And please remember that `while` and `if` statements in Python do not use parentheses.  That's a C/C++ thing that is not part of Python.

Comment: And if `U.Population` is an integer column, there is no need for `int(x[5])`.  It's already an integer.  In your last line, if you're printing everything in the row, you can do `print("..." % tuple(x))`.

Comment: @NathanRoberts Thank you, double checking that fixed my issue lol. I was mixing up the first name and last name of the record with each other which obviously caused it to not return anything. Thank you for helping me realize what should have been obvious.

Comment: @jprism You're welcome